# Identify a case no by 3 other variables in R

Tags: merge, duplicates, pid

I have a dataframe A containing data from 3.000 students from the year 2023. Data includes an PID, their town, gender and the study start date:

PID    town      sex     date

1       A         M       1.1.2018

2       B         F       7.3.2016

Most of the students are already in another dataframe B containing about 6.000 students and their longitudinal annual data from 2018-2022, and each student did get *another* pid in dataframe B.

Is there a way to give each student in dataframe A the same pid from dataframe B based on these 3 variables? I could than merge the two data frames…

In case of a student with the same town, study subject and date, I would have to address the case manually based on other variables.

Or can I first merge these two dataframes and than give the students with the same value in these 3 variables a new, "combined" PID?

I honestly have no clue how to solve this. I read about find duplicates (vec_duplicate_detect) but cant find a solution.